# It is possible to use a different stress tensor than Cauchy stress tensor when creating a custom material law?

Tags: finite-element-method, solidmechanics

I would like to use Mathematica to solve some solid mechanics problems, which will include an implementation of a different model than the ones that Mathematica offers. The way how to write custom material laws is shown in [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html#1096943823) on hypoelastic materials.
The module in the example gives the Cauchy stress tensor, which is then used to construct a PDE. It is possible to use a different stress tensor like Kirchhoff, 1st or 2nd Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change those. But let's step back a little. First we have differentiate between [Hypoelastic material models](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html#1096943823) and [Hyperelastic material models](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/Hyperelasticity.html). Although the names are somewhat similar these material laws are for different things. A Hypoelastic material model assumes a linear stress-strain relation ship and for that the differences between PK1, PK2 and Cauchy stress are minimal. So there is no need to use different ones.

Now, Hyperelastic material models are a whole different ball of wax. Here, indeed the different stresses play a role. Quoting from [this section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/Hyperelasticity.html#1707495120):

1. The First Piola-Kirchhoff stress is used for the equilibrium
   equation, because we want to express things in the initial
   configuration.
2. The Second Piola-Kirchhoff stress is commonly used for the
   constitutive equation, because the PK2 is compatible with the
   Green-Lagrange strain and the right Cauchy tensor.
3. The Cauchy stress is used to express the stress in the deformed
   object, if that is of interest.

You have the parameter `"EquilibriumStressMeasure"` (defaults to PK1), `"ConstitutiveStressMeasure"` (defaults to PK2) and the `"OutputStressMeasure"` (defaults to Cauchy) that you can set and change. The conversion between these stress measures happens automatically.

`"ConstitutiveStressMeasure"` defines what stress measure is used in your material law; that's probably what you are looking for. Sometimes one want to see the different `"OutputStressMeasure"`, but ultimately the Cauchy stress measure is what you want.

See examples of their usage in the section on the [St. Venant-Kirchhoff](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/Hyperelasticity.html#567942995) model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a list of supported stresses? Is it possible to use a Kirchhoff stress? I tried it and it does not seem supported.

Comment: @lemurman, PK1,PK2 and Cauchy are build in. You could in principal convert it yourself

Comment: @lemurman, I just added code for the conversion to Kirchhoff stress, this will be available in version 13.2.